# Oracle PLSQL Fiscal Period Calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

So, we have a table with companies and what their fiscal year month end is.   For example, for Apple, it is September (9), for Dell it is January (1), for Union Pacific is it December (12), for Axos it is June (6).

Then there is another table with some data entry, and a date which represents the date the data reflects.   Basically it is a calendar date like 12/7/2021, or 9/6/2020, or 3/7/2022.

I need to come up with some algorithm where I can take that date, and based on the fiscal year month end, derive a value for the date in this manner:   4Q22 (4th quarter of fiscal year 2022),  FY23 (fiscal year 2023), 3Q21 (3rd quarter fiscal year 2021.

So in the case of say Axos, if the date on the data is 6/3/2022, I can get 2 values:  4Q22 & FY22.    But, for Apple, if the date on the data is 6/2/2022, then the dates would be:  3Q22 & FY22.

If anyone can help with some logic for this, it would help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: So, let's say the Fiscal Year End is 6 (June).   A date of 6/3/2022 would give 4Q22.    But say the fiscal year end is 12 (December).  A date of 6/3/2022 would give 2Q22.   So, I pass in a date, and depending on the Fiscal Year End Month, I calculate what quarter the date I pass falls in to.

Comment: Not answerable given the data. You'd also have to know how they structure their fiscal months, which are generally not the same as a calendar month. For example, some companies use a 4-4-5 fiscal calendar, meaning each quarter has two months of four weeks and one month of five weeks, totaling 13 weeks, which obviously does not match the calendar months. This is done so that each fiscal quarter has the same number of weeks. When enough "extra" days have accumulated, one of the fiscal quarters may be extended to be 4-5-5. Other popular fiscal quarter structures are 4-5-4 and 5-4-4.

Comment: In our case, all are simply quarters, in 3 month increments.   So, might by Q1 is January, Q2 is March, Q3 is June, Q4 is October.   Or, if the company has a different fiscal calendar:  Q1 might by September, Q2 is December, Q3 is March and Q4 is June.    I know the fiscal month end, June or September, or August.   And based on this, I want to know what quarter it falls into for that company, based on their fiscal calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the date by the number of months for the fiscal year end, and then just convert to strings:

```
  to_char(add_months(trunc(data_date, 'MM'), 12 - fy_end_month), '"FY"YY') as fy
  to_char(add_months(trunc(data_date, 'MM'), 12 - fy_end_month), 'Q"Q"YY') as fq
```

With your examples that would give:

> | COMPANY | FY_END_MONTH | DATA_DATE | FY | FQ |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Apple | 9 | 02-JUN-22 | FY22 | 3Q22 |
> | Axos | 6 | 03-JUN-22 | FY22 | 4Q22 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ff80c63c1a332861c592e58ed9340516) cross-joining all the dates with all the companies so you can see all the combinations, not just the two above (and the intermediate values); and also showing the result for all months in this year for all four companies.

Comment: This almost works I think.  One question:  Say my fiscal month end is February (2).   And I pass the data date of 6/3/2022.  So, that should give me 2Q22, as March, April & May are Q1, and June, July & August are Q2, of FY 2022.    But, your FQ calculation gives 2Q23.   So, appears to be slightly off perhaps:          SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE('06032022','MMDDYYYY'), 'MM'), 12 - 2), 'Q"Q"YY') as fq FROM dual;

Comment: But you said 6/3/2022 is 4Q22 if year-end is 6, which implies FY22 mean 2021-2022; and therefore FY23 means 2022-2023. For a company with year-end 2, any date after Feb 2022 would be in 2022-2023, which by that logic should be FY23, and 6/3/2022 would be 2Q23 for that company. You can't have different rules for different companies or based on today's date, surely?

Comment: OK, my bad.  Doing these date calculations and such can get a bit confusing.   This appears to be working.

Comment: In other words... For Axos financial year 2021-2022 is FY22 is July 2021 to June 2022, so 6/3/2022 (or 2022-06-03) falls in that FY, as 4Q22. For this new company financial year 2022-2023 is FY23 is March 2022 to February 2023, so 6/3/2022 falls in that FY, as 2Q23?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fiscal_years(company, fy_end_month) AS
SELECT 'Apple',          9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dell',           1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Union Pacific', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Axos',           6 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE calendar_dates (dt) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-07-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-07-03' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can subtract months equal than the month of the company's fiscal year end (unless it is 12 when you subtract nothing) and then use `TO_CHAR` to get your required format:

```sql
SELECT f.company,
       c.dt,
       TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS(c.dt, -MOD(fy_end_month, 12)), '"FY"YYYY')
         || TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS(c.dt, 12 - fy_end_month), '"-"YYYY')
         AS fy,
       TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS(c.dt, -MOD(fy_end_month, 12)), 'Q"Q"YY') AS quarter
FROM   calendar_dates c
       CROSS JOIN fiscal_years f
ORDER BY company, dt
```

*Note: if you had details of which company the date applied to then you could use an `INNER JOIN` but the example above just applies all the dates to all companies using a `CROSS JOIN`.*

Which outputs:

> | COMPANY | DT | FY | QUARTER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Apple | 09-JUN-20 | FY2019-2020 | 3Q19 |
> | Apple | 12-JUL-21 | FY2020-2021 | 4Q20 |
> | Apple | 03-JUL-22 | FY2021-2022 | 4Q21 |
> | Axos | 09-JUN-20 | FY2019-2020 | 4Q19 |
> | Axos | 12-JUL-21 | FY2021-2022 | 1Q21 |
> | Axos | 03-JUL-22 | FY2022-2023 | 1Q22 |
> | Dell | 09-JUN-20 | FY2020-2021 | 2Q20 |
> | Dell | 12-JUL-21 | FY2021-2022 | 2Q21 |
> | Dell | 03-JUL-22 | FY2022-2023 | 2Q22 |
> | Union Pacific | 09-JUN-20 | FY2020-2020 | 2Q20 |
> | Union Pacific | 12-JUL-21 | FY2021-2021 | 3Q21 |
> | Union Pacific | 03-JUL-22 | FY2022-2022 | 3Q22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=df2fdd95508aa5a7fdffcfd09b4c4c0d)*

Comment: This appears to be working.   I am running this through a bunch of dates to test and will give some feedback to you shortly.    Thanks!